Regularity of $K$-algebras preserved by tensoring with field extensions
$\newcommand{\imax}{\mathfrak{m}}$I am trying to solidify my understanding of regularity and smoothness over a field, and I have arrived at the following algebraic question that I can't quite see how to resolve.
In my setup, I have that $K$ is an algebraically closed field, $L/K$ is an algebraically closed extension of $K$, and $R$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra.
My understanding of the behavior of smoothness/regularity suggests that the following is true: $R$ is a regular ring (i.e., for each maximal ideal $\imax$ of $R$, the local ring $R_\imax$ is a regular local ring) if and only if $R\otimes_K L$ is a regular ring. I know this can probably be proven using the relationship of smoothness and regularity for schemes over perfect fields, but I am looking for a concrete approach using only commutative algebra.
My main concern is that I don't have a good way of concretely writing down the maximal ideals of $R\otimes_k L$, and so it's not clear to me how to say anything about the local rings $(R\otimes_K L)_\imax$ as $\imax$ runs through the maximal ideals of $R\otimes_K L$. My intuition is to try to relate this to the Jacobian corank, since that is a much nicer way of working with regularity than manually fighting with the rings, but I'm not sure I see how.
I would welcome any hints or ideas.

I think the phrase you're looking for is "geometric regularity", you can probably find some information on the Stacks Project with that search term. I'd caution that regular does not always imply geometrically regular; for example, the tensor product of fields need not be a domain, e.g. $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$, although this doesn't fit into your hypotheses. Geometric regularity might only allow for finite extensions of the base field, however...
